# TensorFlow Dataset API tensor evaluation within map function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have the following dataset input function to create a Dataset generator.

```
def dataset_input_fn(filenames, shuffle, batch_size, sample):
    def parser(record):
        features = {
            'mean_rgb': tf.FixedLenFeature([1024], tf.float32),
            'category': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
        }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, features)

        vrv = parsed['mean_rgb']
        label = tf.cast(parsed['category'], tf.int32)
        return {"mean_rgb": vrv}, label

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(parser)
    if sample:
        dataset = dataset.flat_map(
            lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((x, y)).repeat(oversample_classes(y))
        )
        dataset = dataset.filter(undersampling_filter)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100 * batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).repeat(1)
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    return features, labels
```

I am trying to follow [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14451) to over/subsample data based on the label. Within my `dataset.flat_map` function I iterate over each label and would like to determine how often to repeat it. However, y is a Tensor, and I am unable to evaluate it as an integer. When I try `sess.run(label)` I get

> ValueError: Fetch argument 
>   cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("arg1:0", shape=(),
>   dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph.)

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for that error? It looks like the problem might be outside the `dataset_input_fn()`, since it does not appear to run any code that would trigger that exception. ("Fetch argument" suggests that it's from a `sess.run()` call.)